# Using Alamofire & Argo: Could not find member 'None'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a trouble with Argo parsing a Alamofire response on Swift. It says:

Could not find member 'None'

I am really noob with Swift and I have no idea what can be happening. I tried using nil and &error instead of .None but still not working

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import Argo
import Runes

public class ApiConnector{

    private final var serverHost = "http://192.168.1.2/gpio-web/api/v1/api.php";

    func readPin(pin: Int) -> String{
        var result = "empty"
        Alamofire.request(.GET, serverHost, parameters: ["action": "input", "pins": pin])
            .response { (request, response, data, error) in
                let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: .None)
                if let j: AnyObject = json {
                    let value = JSONValue.parse(j)
                    let response = Response.decode(value)
                }

        }

        return result;

    }


}

struct Response {
    let status: String;
}

 extension Response: JSONDecodable {
    static func create(status: String) -> Response {
        return Response(status: status)
    }

    static func decode(j: JSONValue) -> Response? {
        return Response.create
            <*> j <| "status"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `nil` to both the *options* and *error* parameters:

```
let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)
```

But you probably should be using the error field, and responding to an error if it occurs:

```
var error: NSError?
let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error)

if (json == nil && error != nil) {
    let error = error!
    // do something with error
}
```

That said, you're trying to do here *what Alamofire can already do for you*: parse JSON.

Instead of using `.response()`, use `.responseJSON(:_)`. This will convert the object for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about responseJSON :)